# How to display image which is in binary form in SQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using this code but image is not displaying full. This code is displaying one forth part of image rather full image.

```
<?php 
echo '<img src="data:'.$image_mime_type.';base64,'.base64_encode($rs["Pic"]).'" alt="My image alt" />';
?>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: `$rs["Pic"]` contains image path?

Comment: no it contain binary value. like this 02030405060708090A0BFFC........

Comment: Could you add some more information pls?

Comment: and what is the result of ECHO??

Comment: It display some part of image not full image.

Comment: can u plz share the result of ECHO?

Comment: i have screen shot but this cannot display here .

Comment: you can add in question.

Comment: i have attached screen shot in quest.

Comment: its fine, can u plz chk the image path in firebug? and share it, its half or full?

Comment: why don't you create a temporary file from $rs["Pic"] and point the image to that file?

Comment: Data is in binary form in SQL database.

Comment: danish did you checked the image path in firebug? or source

Comment: Yes I understand that data is in binary format in database that is why I suggested to create an image file by using something like BinaryWriter.Write(all the bytes from the files) and then open the file in some picture viewer.

Comment: in firebug something showing like this 
<img alt="My image alt" src="data:image/;base64,/9j/2wBDAAQCAgICAgQCA....

Comment: Is the image corrupt? or does it display all the images half te size? btw storing images in the database isn't the best solution 99 out 100 times.

Comment: YES. all the images are displaying half. and i agree it is not good approach. but i need solution at the same.

Comment: @DanishAhmad It is highly advisable to accept one of the answer, if you are still stuck with your problem then you need to explain your problem with few more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$path = $rs["Pic"];
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
//echo $base64;

echo '<img src="'.$base64.'" alt="My image alt" />';
```

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(ÿØÿÛ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in... path

Answer (score 0):

If you use just BLOB (Guess it to be blob)

Then it is not enough to store image data which you provided in question.

You have to use instead MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB

```
max size of

BLOB: ~ 63KB
MEDIUMBLOB: ~ 16MB
LONGBLOB: ~ 4GB
```

More information about the length of BLOB and other MySql fields you can see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

The four `BLOB` types are `TINYBLOB`, `BLOB`, `MEDIUMBLOB`, and `LONGBLOB`. Try changing it to `MEDIUMBLOB` or `LONGBLOB`. I had similar issue where I was not getting full image (but, getting some part of image). This is one of the most probably reason where your image didn't get stored completely in db. After changing table structure you need to upload new/same image and see if problem resolved.